# Creating a tar archive from a file list AND removing the full path

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

I'm trying to combine two options for creating a tar archive, but they don't work well together. I don't know what's the problem.

I use:

```
tar -C /var/www/website html -cvzf html.tgz -T /tmp/htmllist.txt
```

If I use only the -C option it creates a tar archive with only a relative path "./html/", but ALL the files inside that folder. I don't want this.

Then if I use only the -T option it creates a tar archive with only the required files, but the path is absolute "/var/www/website/html/whatever.html". I don't want this either.

I want a combination of the two, but somehow it doesn't work.

The folder structure is:

```
/var/www/website/html/
```

- Lots of .html files

The /tmp/htmllist.txt folder contains lines like:

- /var/www/website/html/file1.html
- /var/www/website/html/file5.html
- /var/www/website/html/file32.html

And so on.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: If you `cd /var/www/website` and use relative file paths in `/tmp/htmllist.txt` then `tar` will use relative paths in the archive. You can also use `find` and pipe the output to `tar ... -T -`.

Answer (score 2):

Tar works the other way around when using `-T`. It archives the files including full path. If you don't want the path, strip it on extracting, for example,

Create tarball

```
tar -C /var/www/website html -cvzf html.tgz -T /tmp/htmllist.txt
```

Extract tarball

```
tar -xvf html.tgz --strip-path=3
```

This strips three components from the output path, i.e. /var/www/website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, this tarball is generated for the web users to download so I don't expect them to use strip path or any complicated thing. Plus I don't want them to read the full path. Is there anyother solution?

Comment: Or maybe I can compress, extract, and recompress again ? This is unefficient though....

Comment: The non-obvious solution would be to change into the source directory and do something like tar -cvzf foo.tgz *.html

Comment: It's not *.html It's a specific selection of certain .html files